# How to add % in the head of tbl_summary

Tags: r, gtsummary

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reprex)
y <-c('A','B','C','A')
x <-c('male','male','female',NA)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
reprex()
tbl_summary(df)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvzCZ.png)

I want to add 100% next to N=4. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

If your headings are always going to sum to 100%, then you could try modifying the header to add '(100%)' manually:

```
tbl_summary(df) %>% 
  modify_header(update = "stat_0" ~ "N = {n} (100%)")
```

For other scenarios, the [`modify_header()`](http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/modify.html) function in `gtsummary` should be able to do what you want.